# Intellij IDEA выдаёт ошибку при запуске работающих программ. Как исправить?

Tags: intellij-idea

```
Error:Internal error: (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/CollectionsKt
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/CollectionsKt
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadModules(JpsProjectLoader.java:281)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadModules(JpsProjectLoader.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadFromDirectory(JpsProjectLoader.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:100)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:266)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/CollectionsKt
    at org.rust.jps.RustJpsModelSerializerExtension.getModulePropertiesSerializers(RustJpsModelSerializerExtension.kt:9)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.getModulePropertiesSerializer(JpsProjectLoader.java:344)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadModule(JpsProjectLoader.java:298)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.access$000(JpsProjectLoader.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader$2.call(JpsProjectLoader.java:276)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader$2.call(JpsProjectLoader.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:37)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: `Error:Internal error: (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/CollectionsKt` кажется библиотеку не может найти. Вы Maven установили?

Comment: И добавили ли ее в артефакт?

Comment: @Saidolim это не сторонний проект, это мой проект, который запускался, а теперь нет. Произошло (припоминаю) возможно после обновления плагина `kotlin`, хотя кода на нём нет. Плагин отключил. Пробовал другие проекты запускать - тот же эффект. Что то видимо в самой IDEA